# Replace images source for all images

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey

I want to replace the `src` attribute for all images matching a regex using Greasemonkey scripting.
Example:

Replace `http://aff.kooora.com/i/z3.gif`

With `http://example.com/aff.kooora.com/i/z3.gif`

I have no experience in scripting but this is what I came up with:

```
var allImg=document.getElementsByTagName("img"), i=0, img;
var pattern = aff\.kooora\.com/([A-Za-z0-9/._]*);
while(img=allImg[i++])
{
    result = pattern.exec(img);
    if (result!=null) 
        img.src=img.src.replace(result, 'http://example.com/' + result);
}
```

It doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regular expression is the problem, you need to wrap it in slashes (otherwise the interpreter has no clue that it should treat that as a regexp):

```
var allImg=document.getElementsByTagName("img"), i=0, img;

var pattern = /^http\:\/\/aff\.kooora\.com\/(.*)$/;

while (img = allImg[i++])
{
    if (img.src.match(pattern)) {
        img.src = img.src.replace(pattern, 'http://example.com/aff.kooora.com/$1');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! You didn't get the regex right, though. This is the edited working version  `var allImg=document.getElementsByTagName("img"), i=0, img;

var pattern = /^http\:\/\/aff\.kooora\.com\/(.*)$/;

while (img = allImg[i++])
{
    if (img.src.match(pattern)) {
        img.src = img.src.replace(pattern, 'http://example.com/?url=aff.kooora.com/$1');
  
      }
}
`

Comment: Ah I see, the "aff.kooora.com" was missing in the replacement - fixed that!

Answer (score 3):

Just an alternative.

In this Greasemonkey script, [ProxyLoadIMG](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/76780), this is accomplished without using regex.

It was created to load images through a proxy.
Only the images. Links and other content remains untouched.

```
var proxy = 'https://proxytea.appspot.com/'

for (var x=0; x<document.images.length; x++) {
    imagem = document.images[x];
    imagem.src = imagem.src.replace(location.protocol + '//', proxy);
}
```

http://aff.kooora.com/i/any.jpg becomes https://proxytea.appspot.com/aff.kooora.com/i/any.jpg
http://aff.kooora.com/i/z3.gif becomes https://proxytea.appspot.com/aff.kooora.com/i/z3.gif
and so on...

No RegEx needed :)

Comment: It worked perfectly, with much less hassle. Is there a way to make it include the CSS file through the proxy as well?

Comment: Yes. Just like `document.images` is a collection of all images in the page, `document.styleSheets` is a collection of the styles. You can use a similar code to load the CSS through the proxy.

Comment: This script does the same thing to all links instead of images http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/77701 and this one loads everything through a random proxy http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/77042

Comment: I modified the script as such: `var proxy = 'https://proxytea.appspot.com/'

for (var x=0; x<document.styleSheets.length; x++) {
    imagem = document.styleSheets[x];
    imagem.href = imagem.href.replace(location.protocol + '//', proxy);
}` But I think I'm missing something because it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function replaceImages(oldUrl, newUrl) {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img')
    for (i = 0; i<imgs.length; i++) {
        imgs[i].src = imgs[i].src.replace(oldUrl, remoteUrl)
    }
}

replaceImages('http://aff.kooora.com/i/z3.gif', 'http://example.com/aff.kooora.com/i/z3.gif')
```

This is also great if you're working on a local version of a site and you can't be bothered to download all their image content