# How to replace HTML code of a pop-up with Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Good day everyone,

I started to work with Tampermonkey (or Greasemonkey for Firefox users), and I would like to replace a big part of my HTML code by another.

The complex part of my problem is that the code I want to replace is in a pop-up. When I click on the button to get the pop-up inside the page, the code that I want to change appears on the development tool. Until I don't click on that button, that part of code wont appear. So the userscript doesn't affect the pop-up..

The link to the page (You need to put a UK or US address to get the button "Customize this item" to the pop-up): https://www.clos19.com/en-us/hennessy-engravable-xo-p-100711
(Drink with moderation, btw.)

[image: example]
<sub>(source: [hostpic.xyz](https://hostpic.xyz/files/15651932042641236109.png))</sub>

I have affected the pop-up from the console, only when the pop-up appeared. But I want the pop-up to be affected even before it appears.

I would like to turn this part of the pop-up

```
<mh-image format="dialog-half-width" src="/medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw" alt="">
    <div class="image-map-wrapper ">
        <img src="/medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw&amp;resize=490px:653px 490w,
            /medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw&amp;resize=980px:1306px 980w" 
            class="img-format__dialog-half-width" title="" alt="" srcset="
            /medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw&amp;resize=480px:640px 480w,
            /medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw&amp;resize=960px:1280px 960w,
            /medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw&amp;resize=370px:493px 370w,
            /medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw&amp;resize=740px:986px 740w,
            /medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw&amp;resize=490px:653px 490w,
            /medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw&amp;resize=980px:1306px 980w,                        
            /medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw&amp;resize=536px:715px 536w,
            /medias/HENNESSY-COGNAC-XO-75CL-100711-7.jpg?context=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw&amp;resize=1072px:1430px 1072w
            " sizes="(min-width: 1280px) 536px,
            (min-width: 800px) 490px,
            (min-width: 640px) 370px,
            480px">
    </div>
</mh-image>
```

in to that

```
<mh-image format="dialog-half-width" src="https://mypic.png" alt="">
    <div class="image-map-wrapper ">
        <img src="https://mypic.png" sizes="(min-width: 1280px) 536px,
            (min-width: 800px) 490px,
            (min-width: 640px) 370px,
            480px">
    </div>
</mh-image>
```

I made a lot a searches before writing this. I tried to replace the actual picture with mine by using a RegExp. If I find the pattern (which contains the path to the picture), I would replace it with my picture. (source of that solution: [Replace images source for all images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071677/replace-images-source-for-all-images))

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.clos19.com/en-us/hennessy-engravable-xo-p-100711
// @grant        none
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js
// ==/UserScript==

var $ = window.jQuery;

$(document).ready(function() {
  var pattern = new RegExp('/^\/medias\/HENNESSY\-\COGNAC\-XO\-75CL\-100711\-7\.jpg\?context\=bWFzdGVyfGltYWdlc3wzNjA3MjA3fGltYWdlL2pwZWd8aW1hZ2VzL2hlNS9oMmEvODk0ODc2ODQ0MDM1MC5qcGd8ZGZmNTFiMjk2OTAzYWZkMDc3OTA4Mjg4Y2QzNjBiMTUzOWMzODg4NjhiNDIyMDg3NDdlNGE3OGQyZjdiN2Q0Yw');
  var allImg=document.getElementsByTagName("img"), i=0, img;

while (img = allImg[i++])
{
    if (img.src.match(pattern)) {
        img.src = img.src.replace(pattern, 'https://mypic.png');
    }
}
});
```

Wait.. The pop-up is triggered when you click the customize button..

```
<button ($click)="checkStock()" class="customise button button-primary expanded transparent">
    Customize this item
    <i class="icon icon-edit-pencil"></i>
</button>
```

So I'm asking myself if it is possible to trigger a userscript function at the same time..

Thank you in advance for your help, people!

*EDIT: Thanks to @wOxxOm, I managed to detect the pop-up with the userscript. But I still can't modify it. I tried this:*

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.clos19.com/en-us/hennessy-engravable-xo-p-100711
// @grant        none
// @require      http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements (
    ".reveal-overlay",
    replaceDuplicate
);

function replaceDuplicate (c) {
    document.getElementsByTagName("mh-image").src = "https://mypic.png";
    document.getElementsByClassName("img-format_dialog-half-width").src = "https://mypic.png";
    document.getElementsByClassName("img-format_dialog-half-width").srcset = "";
}
```

Comment: Use MutationObserver or waitForKeyElements.

Comment: Hi @wOxxOm, thanks for your help. I'm currently trying with waitForKeyElement(). I checked with a simple alert() function and it manages to recognize the pop-up. Thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming back with the answer. We had to look into parent and child elements.

```
waitForKeyElements (
    ".reveal-overlay",
    replaceDuplicate
);

function replaceDuplicate (c) {
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    elem.setAttribute("src", "mypic.png");
    elem.setAttribute("height", "768");
    elem.setAttribute("width", "1024");
    elem.setAttribute("alt", "TM - Customizable image");
    var parentElem = document.getElementsByClassName("class_of_the_div")[0];
    console.log(parentElem);
    // Remove all previous images
    parentElem.innerHTML = '';
    // Add new customizable image
    parentElem.appendChild(elem);
}
```

Thanks!